# getting multiple rows from parse.com into dynamic textblocks in windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone 8 app and am using parse.com as my back-end services. I have been trying to load all the rows from my parse.com object (databse table) into the dynamic textblocks. I am adding the textblock on button click which will show the data from the parse.com. but my problem is I have 2 rows coming from parse.com and my 2 dynamically created textblocks are sitting at the same place on each other. but i want it to create a new textblock for each row coming from parse.com

this is my XAML code for the page

```
 <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ic">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!--<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Text="{Binding TextBlock}" FontSize="20" />-->
                        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding times}" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" />-->
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Button x:Name="BtnRefresh" Content="Refresh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="316,-101,0,0" Width="140" Click="BtnRefresh_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

this is my dynamic code adding textblocks with my data which is coming from parse.com

```
 public async void BtnRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var query = from users in ParseObject.GetQuery("Users")
                    orderby users.CreatedAt ascending
                    select users ;
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();

        foreach (var users in results)
        {
            TextBlock TextBlock = new TextBlock();

            var username = users.Get<string>("username");


               TextBlock.Text = "User: " + username.ToString();

               ContentPanel.Children.Add(TextBlock);

        }
```

I want this code to show multiple textblocks according to the rows i get from parse.com

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to add them dynamically in the code behind, you could try using a scrollviewer and a stackpanel and then dynamically adding them to the stackPanel. So:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentStack" />
        <Button x:Name="BtnRefresh" Content="Refresh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="316,-101,0,0" Width="140" Click="BtnRefresh_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
public async void BtnRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var query = from users in ParseObject.GetQuery("Users")
                orderby users.CreatedAt ascending
                select users ;
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();

    foreach (var users in results)
    {
        TextBlock TextBlock = new TextBlock();

        var username = users.Get<string>("username");


           TextBlock.Text = "User: " + username.ToString();

           ContentStack.Children.Add(TextBlock);

    }
```

Comment: thnx alot for the reply. I actually got this one the same day I posted this. I was using the ContentPanel instead of StackPanel. It worked after using StackPanel.